# Angular: there is a way to interact with second-level child component from a directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, children

In HTML template, I have the following implementation:

```
<tr sliding>
  <td>Field 1</td>
  <td>Field 2</td>
  <td>
    <app-sliding>Field 3</app-sliding>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have the following directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sliding]'
})
export class SlidingDirective {

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
  public onHover(e: Event): void {
    const el = e.target as HTMLElement;
    const appSliding = el.querySelector('app-sliding') as AppSlidingComponent;

    if (cdSliding) {
      appSliding.show();
    }
  }
}
```

And the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sliding',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class AppSlidingComponent {
  show() {
    console.log('yes');
  }
}
```

I would like that when the mouse overs `<tr>` DOM element, the directive call the method `show()` of `AppSlidingComponent`.

I tried to use @ViewChild implementation but I not able to see a second level child.

`querySelector` find the DOM element but considered as HTMLElement, not AppSlidingComponent.

There is a way to interact with the child component from the directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild)**  inside directive to get projected component instance.

```
@ContentChild
(SlidingComponent, {static:false}) compInst:SlidingComponent;

@HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event'])
  public onHover(e: Event): void {
    const el = e.target as HTMLElement;
    const appSliding = el.querySelector('app-sliding');
    this.compInst.show();
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfnhsm)